# Embed Google Analytics in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4, google-analytics

I set up a website with laravel 4.
The website has no front facing site ...
The website sends a file as response to a link earlier generated.

So there is no html / blade template.

How can I embed Google Analytics within Laravel without using html output?
Is there a chance to call the Google Analytics JavaScript with php?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Analytics Measurement Protocol is what you're looking for:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/

It allows you to send hits directly to Google Analytics via simple HTTP requests, which you should easily be able to do from your PHP back-end.

Comment: Thanks, that actually solved my problem. Is there a way to set the IP address of the client which calls my website. Right now Google Analytics recognize the server where my php script is running and not the client which calls the script.

Comment: Yep. With the measurement protocol you can override both the [IP address](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uip) and the [User Agent string](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ua).

Comment: Thanks again. That was exactly, that I was looking for. I haven't recognized both parameter ... Great API :)

Comment: Having a hard time finding an actual example of the best way to submit the data...

Comment: @dcolumbus did you see this page? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#commonhits